# Why Accept button of Google+ Sign in page is disabled in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios7, google-plus

I am trying to add Google Sign in to my iOS application. I am quite new to iOS application development.

I followed the official Google guide, integrate the `Google SDK`, placed a button on my view controller and call authentication.

After filling in my email and password, I could see the the following page, but the `accept` button is always disabled, why is that? I am running this application in the emulator.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)handleGoogleSignIn:(id)sender
{

    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];

    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    signIn.clientID = kClientId;
    signIn.scopes = @[ @"profile" ];
    signIn.delegate = self;

    [signIn authenticate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That page does not look right - I suspect that the JS or CSS hasn't loaded properly. Could you try resetting the simulator and trying it again, hopefully the full page will load in that case. Or clear the cache from the Safari options in the Settings app.